# Remove minor ticks in Vega Lite date x-axis

Tags: vega-lite

I have the following Vega Lite spec

```
{
  "config": {
    "view": {"stroke": "transparent"},
    "mark": {"tooltip": null},
    "axis": {
      "grid": false,

      "labelAngle": 0,
      "labelFont": "museo-sans-300",
      "labelFontSize": 15,
      "labelFontWeight": "normal",
      "titleFont": "museo-sans-300",
      "titleFontSize": 15,
      "titleFontWeight": "normal"
    }
  },
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {"name": "data"},
  "mark": {
    "type": "line",
    "interpolate": "monotone",
    "point": {"filled": false, "fill": "white"}
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "date",
      "type": "temporal",
      "timeUnit": "monthdate",
      "axis": {"title": null,"tickMinStep": 1}
    },
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field":"%"},
    "color": {
      "field": "metric",
      "type": "nominal",
      "legend": {
        "labelFont": "museo-sans-300",
        "labelFontSize": 15,
        "title": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "padding": 0
      }
    }
  },
  "width": 500,
  "datasets": {
    "data": [
      {
        "date": "2019-11-28",
        "metric": "linehaul_util_perc",
        "%": 48.36678571428571
      },
      {
        "date": "2019-11-29",
        "metric": "linehaul_util_perc",
        "%": 57.74388888888889
      },
      {"date": "2019-12-03", "metric": "linehaul_util_perc", "%": 57.25},
      {
        "date": "2019-12-04",
        "metric": "linehaul_util_perc",
        "%": 71.37883720930233
      },
      {"date": "2019-11-28", "metric": "recovery_perc", "%": 62.7},
      {"date": "2019-11-29", "metric": "recovery_perc", "%": 63.1},
      {"date": "2019-12-02", "metric": "recovery_perc", "%": 126.1},
      {"date": "2019-12-03", "metric": "recovery_perc", "%": 80.4},
      {"date": "2019-12-04", "metric": "recovery_perc", "%": 60.4},
      {"date": "2019-11-28", "metric": "rolling_recovery", "%": 73.9},
      {"date": "2019-11-29", "metric": "rolling_recovery", "%": 73.3},
      {"date": "2019-11-30", "metric": "rolling_recovery", "%": 71.5},
      {"date": "2019-12-01", "metric": "rolling_recovery", "%": 72.2},
      {"date": "2019-12-02", "metric": "rolling_recovery", "%": 76.5},
      {"date": "2019-12-03", "metric": "rolling_recovery", "%": 76.6},
      {"date": "2019-12-04", "metric": "rolling_recovery", "%": 75.5}
    ]
  }
}
```

Which produces the following image

[image]

which is correct except that I only want ticks to show on the days with text (i.e. major ticks). Setting min tick distance to 1 didn't seem to work, although I am able to change this with tickCount. However this would require a bit of extra logic to first determine the number of days in the set, so it would be great to be able to do it without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I just did not read the docs closely enough. This problem can be solved using tickCount because it can take 'day' as an argument, which is what I require.